# Should I use "got" or "gotten" in the following sentence?

Tags: word-choice, past-participles, got-gotten

I can't figure out whether to use *got* or *gotten* in the following sentence:

> I no longer recognized my own skin, my own feelings, my own thoughts.
>   It was as if the real me had **got/gotten** lost on the highway.

Which is the correct form of the verb?

Comment: British English or American English? (BrE uses *gotten* only dialectally, so I suppose/guess it's AmE)

Comment: I think it is AE because the sentence also uses "recognize" and not "recognise".

Comment: @Andrew Leach I don't really mind. I guess American. So *got* is AE and *gotten* BE?

Comment: No, the other way round. *Gotten* has almost entirely disappeared in BrE.

Comment: janoChen, you can choose *gotten* if you use American English. If not, just use *got*. In the UK, *gotten* is normally only used when people say *ill-gotten* or *forgotten*.

Comment: I just read the following sentence from *Gulliver's Travels (1726)*: "When I had got out of danger, I stopped awhile to..."

Comment: @AndrewLeach Just to weigh in here - AusE is a mix of both BrE and AmE, so "gotten" and "got" are often used interchangeably in Australia.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

[This article](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/gotten) (emphasis mine) would be hard to improve on:

> As past participles of get, **got** and **gotten** both date back to
>   Middle English. The form *gotten* is not used in British English but
>   is very common in North American English, though even there it is
>   often regarded as non-standard.
>
> In North American English, *got* and *gotten* are **not identical in
>   use**. *Gotten* usually implies the [punctive act /] process of
>   obtaining something, as in *he had gotten us tickets for the show*,
>   while *got* implies the state [durative] of possession or ownership,
>   as in *I haven’t got any money*.
>
> [Oxford Dictionaries]

An American might well prefer 'gotten' in the OP; a Brit would probably not, and might well not like the sound of the 'got' version either, choosing to rephrase, as Preetie suggests.

Comment: Although, interestingly, we Brits like to say, "I've forgotten it."

Comment: And we might hear the odd 'begotten' during the next few weeks.

Comment: "In American English *gotten*, although occasionally criticized, is an alternative standard past participle in most senses, esp. “to receive” and “to acquire”: I have gotten (or got) a dozen replies so far." (http://www.thefreedictionary.com/get)

Comment: Even in AmE, the use of *gotten* in a sense of 'became' (as against 'obtained') is very rare: * *gotten lost* .

Comment: I can think of an improvement: mention that "got" alone (without "have") is the ordinary past tense of "get", in the same way as the difference between "ate" and "have eaten". "Have got" is an anomaly.

Comment: @Random832 OP asks only about the choice of participle (choice between had got / had gotten), not about other possible constructions. It is a well-defined and sensible question. How can skewing his question be considered an improvement? It becomes a different question.

Comment: Also a nice referenceable link by Merriam-Webster: http://www.learnersdictionary.com/qa/difference-between-have-got-and-have-gotten

Comment: @Pitarou I think 'forgotten' is dying out too, to an extent. Most people I know would say "I've forgot my wallet" or "I forgot about that" rather than "I've forgotten my wallet" or "I'd forgotten that". Even when it is used, there's typically a distinction between "I (have) forgot X" and "I had forgotten X".

Comment: Internet data would strongly suggest otherwise, Pharap. And I'd say that "I've forgot my homework" would still be unacceptable in an English school. See [forum.wordreference.com/threads/I've/forgot-or-forgotten](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/forgot-or-forgotten.1214483/), for example.

Answer (score 6):

per The Cambridge Encyclopedia of the English Language (p.311):

"Gotten is probably the most distinctive of all the AmE/BrE grammatical
 differences, but British people who try to use it often get it wrong."

Gotten is much more common in AmE.

I like the sound of your use of 'gotten' in that sentence. "...had been lost" sounds so passive, whereas "...had gotten lost" sounds more tragic.

"The child had been lost on the highway."
"The child had gotten lost on the highway."

Which has more impact?

Answer (score 1):

I have heard instances of how "gotten lost" is hated by the British. My copy of *Grammar* by Wren & Martin also lists "got" as the past participle of get.

Base Form: Get

Past Tense: Got

Past Participle: Got

However, as Andrew Leach comments, I have seen many examples of the same in American English.

If I were I you, I would simply say:

I no longer recognized my own skin, my own feelings, my own thoughts. It was as if the real me had *been* lost on the highway.

Comment: Thanks. I think you're right: been it's a better option.

Comment: That's still not equivalent, I think. Been lost implies that you are no longer lost, while gotten lost could be that you got lost, and still are lost.

Comment: @MelPadden is correct, "been" suggests "had been lost, but not any more". "had _become_ lost" would be better. (For some reason got/gotten is very frequently used as a colloquial form of 'to become', possibly more so in American English or by younger generations.)

Answer (score 1):

Having grown up in the UK, but now live in Canada, I have to say that I have never used the word "gotten" other than in words such as forgotten or ill-gotten. I used to find it hard to listen to but it no longer bothers me and seems to make sense when I hear others use it. Languages evolve and this is one of those words which has evolved differently on either side of the Atlantic - that's okay.

I was taught that got/gotten should be used sparingly as it is often redundant or clumsy.
eg:
"I have a cold." vs "I have got a cold." or "I have gotten a cold."
"The child was lost." or "The child became lost." vs "The child had got lost." or "The child had gotten lost."

Comment: "The child became lost." vs "The child had got lost." - To match the tense the former should be "The child had become lost".

Answer (score 0):

In the example given, I would use "gotten." But that's only if you think the word "gotten" has a place in our language. To me, there is a legitimate and useful difference between "got" and "gotten." To say you've "got" something means that you have it, now. To say that you've "gotten" something means that you've obtained or received it in the past. The example given doesn't use "got/gotten" in that way, but given the continued use of the two words in American English, "had gotten lost" sounds better to my ear than "had got lost." It's more a matter of consistency than of correctness.