# Is there past tense form of 'got'?

Tags: past-tense, simple-past-vs-past-perfect, got-gotten

Is 'gotten' the past tense form of 'got' or is there even a word gotten?

Comment: Dupe? http://english.stackexchange.com/q/140124/17611

Comment: Thank you.. Can you answer my one more doubt.?

Comment: *Got* is the past tense of *get*. *Gotten* is the American past participle of *get*. (And *got* is the British past participle of *get*.)

Comment: He said, "I got this book yesterday" when we change this into reported speech he said that he had got /he got that book the previous day?

Comment: In AmE, *"I got this book yesterday"* would change into *"he said he had gotten this book the previous day"*. In BrE, *gotten* is not used.

Comment: @PeterShor It is a little more involved than that Peter. Would you mind looking over my reply, below, to see if you agree with it, please.

Comment: @WS2: the American parts are correct, and I'm sure you know about the British parts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***Got*** is already a past tense. It is the past of 'get'. *I got some bread at the shop*, tells of something that happened in the past.

***Got*** is both a past tense and a past participle. In its past participle form, *I have **got** a blue car*, ***got*** signifies possession - *I am in possession of a blue car*

Thus far all of the above is the same both in Britain and America.

Where ***got*** refers to the process of acquisition, in the perfect and pluperfect Americans say *I have just **gotten** a copy from the library*, whilst we would use **got**. This also applies in reported speech *She told me she had **gotten** married* versus British *She told me she had **got** married*.

When it comes to direct reporting of acquisition, where Americans will say: *Since we last met I have **gotten** anew car*, British will often avoid **got** altogether and say something like: *Since we last met I have acquired/bought/obtained a new car*.

Comment: Could you please explain my reported speech doubt in the comment above? I want to know whether got /had got is used.

Comment: Yes. In the reported case Americans would use *gotten*. *He told me that he had gotten the book yesterday*. In Britain we would use *got* in that instance. And this needs to be added to my reply above - i.e. the reported speech case.

Comment: I understood about the got part I want to know whether its:he said that he had got the book or is it :he said that he got the book?

Comment: @ShonimaNandakumar If you are reporting a past speech of his then it's: *He said that he had got the book*.

Comment: It should probably be noted that not even the English have for**gotten** ***“ill-gotten gains”*** and other similar misbe**gotten** variants, such as when Alfred, Lord Tennyson wrote in *Maud* ɪ. ɪᴠ. iii: “Your father has wealth **well-gotten**, and I am nameless and poor.” Another only-remembered-in-America *‑en* word is the relic form **store-*boughten*** which opposes *home-made* and is preserved now only in certain regional dialects but was once more widespread and even standard.

Comment: Whilst in Britain the form *shop-bought* used to be used, but has mostly disappeared. But *store-boughten* is interesting. I had not previously heard that.

Comment: Would the reason for America having adopted the  -en (*gotten, boughten etc) be that it was the language of the Bible, do you think? Are there any other 17th century forms which survive, which we in Britain may have lost?

Comment: @tchrist I have just been listening to a BBC Radio programme on the history of Christmas music. The carol *Ding Dong Merrily on High* was mentioned. It was apparently a 16th century French dance tune. The modern words were composed in the 19th century and it didn't get into hymnals until 1924. But the composer introduced phrasing like 'let steeple bells be swungen', just to give it that mystical past appeal. So much of medieval Europe was simply invented in the 19th century!